# No such column on sobject error occurring on sObject that does have that column

Tags: api, custom-object, custom-field, sobject

When attempting to update a custom object using SF default API endpoints (`/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/MyCustomObject__c/customId__c/4003`) I am getting a weird error telling me that a column doesn't exist, when it does definitely, in fact, exist for that object.

Specifically, the error I get is:

```
"No such column 'opportunityId__c' on sobject of type YTPStudent__c"
```

Meanwhile, here is what my custom object looks like:

[image: YTPStudent__c]

Here, I am viewing the `YTPStudent__c` object and you can clearly see there exists a column `opportunityId__c`...

This error makes absolutely no sense to me. First off, the user hitting this is an API User with a permission set that allows create/edit/delete access to all of these fields and objects. Secondly, even if it was a permissions issue, we should be getting an unauthorized error, not a does not exist error.

What could be causing such a weird issue?

Comment: I would triple check those permissions for the running user. When the running user doesn't have permission, the field is hidden and acts as though it does not exist at all.

Answer (score 3):

I would agree with Mark Pond's suggestion. I had this issue and found that the dev who setup the new field hadn't given any profiles, including system admin, visibility on the Field Level Security for the new field